# Color output from shell command in Ruby

Tags: ruby, unix, scripting

Here's a simple Ruby script:

```
puts `ls -laG`
```

In OS X's ls, -G is for color.

When run under bash, I get color output. When the above is run from a Ruby script, I don't see color or the ANSI escape sequences in the resulting output.

From what I've read, my guess is it's because the script isn't running as a tty. Is there some way to run the command as if it were being run under a true tty session -- or something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [ls man page in OS X](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ls.1.html), I see a couple of environment variables mentioned.  CLICOLOR enables color (like -G) and CLICOLOR_FORCE (forces color even to non-terminal output).

So I think you'll get what you want with...

```
puts `env CLICOLOR=1 CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -la`
```

You could set the environment variables in your .profile.  In my example, I just used the env command to ensure they're set on the command line.  I left off the -G option since CLICOLOR does the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I should have noted in the question that I'm actually running a different command (rake spec), but I wanted to be generic. Setting an environment variable led me down the right path though -- I found in rspec's source that one can set RSPEC_COLOR=true to force color even if we're not from a tty.

Answer (score 3):

According to the man page you can force it by setting CLICOLOR_FORCE.