# How to preserve colour in command output through Ruby script

Tags: ruby, unix, command-line

```
ls -la # This gives a coloured output.
```

But,

```
puts %x{ ls -la } # The colours aren't preserved here.
```

Is there a way to get coloured output??

Comment: try `ls --color=always`

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I don't see colours on OSX I tested it on linux.

Comment: For OSX you need `CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -G`

Comment: Wow! That worked! Can you post that as answer, will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I would but @sawa has marked your question as a duplicate.  :-(  Can you please change this?  It's a good question, and I need more points! :0)

Comment: How can I refute the this question is not a duplicate? I don't think its duplicate.

Comment: @JikkuJose Put something in the question statement that clearly shows why this isn't the same question. Something like "<other question> does not solve the issue because it deals with <X> when I'm having trouble with <Y>". You don't have to use my exact wording, but make it clear to others in your question statement why these are two different problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color output from shell command in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948359/color-output-from-shell-command-in-ruby)