# Simple clone of unix watch using Ruby (with coloured output)

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am looking to create a simple `unix watch` like command using Ruby to run commands. But colours aren't preserved for some commands. For instance, I was able to preserve the colour while executing:

```
puts %x{ CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 ls -la}
```

* flag suggestion by [john-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24131750/how-to-preserve-colour-in-command-output-through-ruby-script?noredirect=1#comment37241488_24131750)

I am assuming its because the commands switch to a printable text only version when the command is invoked via script, possibly to ease further processing. Have heard of this, but don't have the proper pointer/terms to do a research; is there a way to force the coloured output through a Ruby script? Or 'trick' the commands into thinking its invoked via terminal rather than a script?

I tested without success with the following:

```
puts %x{ CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 rspec --color test_file.rb  }
```

I know there is a well established way to go about this using guard-rspec. But I am pursuing this for a gem that I am building and I need the capability to run arbitrary commands with coloured output preserved.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that the commands you are running switch to a non-colour output when invoked from a script. They detect that their standard output is not a terminal and modify their output accordingly.

Fortunately, you should be able to trick the commands into thinking they are outputting to a terminal by using a [pseudo-terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal). You can do this using the [PTY module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) in Ruby.

I took the following from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1162850) and tested it on Ruby 1.9.3-p392.

```
require 'pty'

PTY.spawn('ls --color=auto') do |stdin, stdout, pid|
  begin
    stdin.each {|line| print line}
  rescue Errno::EIO
    # End of input
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Guard [runs the command](https://github.com/guard/guard/blob/master/lib/guard/sheller.rb#L97) in a *subshell* using  [`Kernel#system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-system). This works for me:

```
$ ruby -e "system('ls -la')"
```

or

```
$ ruby -e "system('rspec test_file.rb')"
```

Comment: Wow thanks it works! I should get to the habit of opening projects that already implements the feature! But, I think I should give credit to the previous one for the answer as its more to the point, despite the fact that I will be using this. Thanks anyways.